# jquery within a javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I am calling a javascript function from within my razor code..but the jquery code within my javascript function doesnot get executed..

- what is the correct way of doing it.

  ```
  function getPosition(id) {
    var c = '#' + id;
   return $c.index();
  }
  ```

**My HTML Table**

```
  <tbody>
      <tr>

         <td>
            @foreach(Result geResults in Model.results)
            {
            @:
              <script>
              {
               getPosition(@geResult.assessmentId);
              }
              </script>
             }
         </td>

      </tr>
  <\tbody>
```

**UPDATE**

As everybody is getting confused i am posting more detail

```
<table>
    <thead>
            <tr>
            @foreach (Assessment geAssessment in Model.assessments)
                {
                    <th id=@geAssessment.AssessmentID>@geAssessment.Name</th>
                }
```

```
        </thead>
        <tbody>
              <tr>
                  @{
                      // add a td for each assessment in body
                    foreach(Assessment geAssessment in Model.assessments)
                    {
                        <td>
                          @foreach (ShortResult geResult in Model.results)
                          {
                             @:
                             <script>
                             {                                                                   getPosition(@geResult.assessmentId);
                              }
                            </script>

                            }
                         </td>  
                                    }
                                 }
              </tr>
         </tbody>
```

i want to return the column index in getPosition function and then print it in the td..hope this clears out any confusions

currently it says getPosition is out of context whereas intellisense shows me getPosition when i code

Comment: What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: `$c` is not defined. You mean `$(c)`.

Comment: Try this `return $('#' + id).index();`. also u need to visit this https://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: I don't think that is how it works... you might need to instead add an element with an onload to load the function. I don't know razor code so I wouldn't really know but that simply just looks wrong. Try adding in a console.log and just try to get something on the console.

Comment: What is the value of this `@geResult.assessmentId` and do you have any element with id of @geResult.assessmentId's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `c` in brackets. It will be like this:

```
function getPosition(id) {
  var c = '#' + id;
 return $(c).index();
}
```

If it doesnt throw

> $ Undefind error

Comment: I have actually defined this id in my td as: <th id=@geAssessment.AssessmentID>@geAssessment.Name</th> and then i try to find the right header/column for each result in tbody...it was getting called before and now it says getPosition does not exist in the current context..I have described my code in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708805/using-javascript-jquery-from-within-razor-code

Comment: this answer seems fine but i am unable to test because of the error see update

Answer (score -1):

first of all check that  your passing the values means getPosition("") is not null secondly write in JavaScript

```
function getPosition($id) {
  var c = '#' + $id +;
 return $(c).index();
}
```

Comment: The change from `id` to `$id` was pointless, wrong syntax has been introduced and you didn’t explain the issue with `$c`.